# Error: Type object has no attribute 'Query'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create my first website using Python + flask and am now having issues trying to add data to SQLite database using Flask-SQLAlchemy.

This is part where I am trying to add user to database but it fails:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('registracija.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']


        user = User.Query(filter_by=username)
        if user.count() == 0:
            user = User(username=username, password=password)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()

            flash('You have registered the username {0}. Please login'.format(username))
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            flash('The username {0} is already in use.  Please try a new username.'.format(username))
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
    else:
        abort(405)
```

And my register.html page:

```
<form method="post" >
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Username: <br />
    Password: <br />
    Please repeat password: <br />
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
   <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />
   <input type="password" name="password" />  <br />
   <input type="password" name="repeatpassword" /> <br /> <br />
   <input type="submit" name="register" value="Registruotis" />
</div>

</form>
```

When I fill form and press register button I get:

> *AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'Query'*

Would be nice if someone could point me what I am doing wrong. I am running Python 3.5 On Windows 10.

Comment: Please post your code here, not on a pastebin, and cut it down to the relevant parts only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user = User.Query(filter_by=username)
```

should be

```
user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
```

All names in Python are case-sensitive: variable names, function names, class names, module names, exception names. If you can get it, set it, call it, construct it, import it, or raise it, it’s case-sensitive. Hence the error you are receiving about user not having any attribute 'Query' when it does have an attribute 'query'.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm.